# Expected expression before ']' token? C

Tags: c++, c

```
  if(!saveItems(item[], DATAFILE, NoOfRecs))
```

the error is:

> Expected expression before ']' token

Comment: Not a lot to go on here, but you probably want `if(!saveItems(item, DATAFILE, NoOfRecs))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified what element of the array `item` you are trying to pass to the function.

`item[]` doesn't mean anything. It has no value. You have to put a number into the brackets. That number is the element of the array. Each element of an array has its own value.

Example broken code where the same mistake is made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int my_array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  my_array[] = 1; // ERROR HERE!
  return 0;
}
```

If you try to compile this, you will get this:

```
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:6:11: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
```

because I didn't tell what element of `my_array` I want to assign 1 to. Do I want to assign it to the first element (`my_array[0]`), the second element, (`my_array[1]`), or the third element (`my_array[2]`)? The compiler doesn't know. You have to tell it.

If `item` if a scalar (not an array), get rid of the [], it's not suppose to be there.

In case you are trying to pass the whole array as an argument, you don't use the brackets even though you are passing an array. If you want to pass the whole array as an argument do this:
`if(!saveItems(item, DATAFILE, NoOfRecs))`

Comment: The notation `item[]` would be legal in a function prototype. It seems likely that OP is attempting to use an array as an argument to the function `saveItems()` here. Using `item` in the function call passes a pointer to the first element of `item[]` as an argument, since array identifiers decay to pointers in most expressions.

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned that. `item[]` is correct syntax if you are using it as a parameter in a function prototype. But when you are calling a function, `item[]` isn't correct.

Comment: thank you; @user91656 if(!saveItems(item, DATAFILE, NoOfRecs)) is work....i though there was a array in it []......i just start learn programming, so.....thx for the help ;)

Comment: `item[]` can also be legal in a declaration, like `extern item[];`.